# TypeORM : insert data in table without entity

Tags: request, insert, runtime, typeorm

I need to create and populate table during runtime

I can create the new table :

```js
const col1 = new TableColumn({
  name: 'id',
  type: 'integer',
  isNullable: false,
  isGenerated: true,
  isPrimary: true
})
const col2 = new TableColumn({
  name: 'test',
  type: 'integer'
})

const table = new Table({
 name: 'admin.yop2',
 columns: \[
   col1,
   col2
 \]
})
await connection.createQueryRunner().createTable(table)
```

I can make a selection on this table :

```js
const qbTest = connection.createQueryBuilder()
qbTest.from('admin.yop2', 'yop')
const ret = await qbTest.getRawMany()
```

But how to do to insert data in this table ?

When i try to use query builder i got an error : `TypeORMError: Cannot build query because main alias is not set (call qb#from method)`

If i try to add a `from` in my queryBuilder i got a select request instead of insert request

```js
const qbTest = connection.createQueryBuilder()
qbTest.insert().into('admin.yop2', [ 'test' ]).values([
      { test: 1 },
      { test: 1 },
      { test: 4 },
      { test: 25 },
      { test: 7 }
    ])

await qbTest1.execute()
```

How to make a correct insert request with the query builder on my unregisterd table ?